# How to inject future sequential input for multi-step time series forecasts in LSTM networks

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm, forecasting

I am trying to do multi-step (i.e., sequence-to-sequence) forecasts for product sales using both (multivariate) sequential and non-sequential inputs.

Specifically, I am using sales numbers as well as some other sequential inputs (e.g., price, is day before holiday, etc...) of the past n days to predict the sales for future m days. Additionally, I have some non-sequential features characterizing the product itself.

Definitions:

- n_seq_features <- number of sequential features (in the multivariate time-series) including sales
- n_non_seq_features <- number of non-sequential features characterizing a product

I got as far as building a hybrid-model, where first the sequential input is passed through some LSTM layers. The output of the final LSTM layer is then concatenated with the non-sequential features and fed into some dense layers.

What I can't quite get my head around, though, is how to input future sequntial input (everything except sales numbers for the following m days) in a way that efficiently utilizes the sequential information (i.e., causality, etc...). For m=1, I can simply input the sequential data for this one day together with the non-sequential input after the LSTM layers, however as soon as m becomes greater than 1 this appears to be a waste of causal information.

The only ways I could think of were:

- to incorporate the sequential information for future m days as features in the LSTM input blowing up the input shape from (..., n, n_seq_features) to (..., n, n_seq_features + m*(n_seq_features-1))
- add a separate LSTM branch handling the future data, the output of which is then 'somehow' fed into the dense layers at the last stage of the model

I only started using LSTM networks a while ago so I unfortunately have only limited intuition on how they are best utilized (especially in hybrid approaches). For this reason, I would like to ask:

1. Is the general approach of injecting sequential and non-sequential input at different stages of the same model (i.e., trained concurrently) useful or would one rather split it into separate models which can be trained independently for more fine-grained control?
2. How is future sequential input injected into an LSTM network to preserve causal information? Can this be achieved with a high-level frontend like KERAS or does it require a very deep dive into the tensorflow backend?
3. Are LSTM networks not the way to go for this specific problem in the first place?

Cheers and thanks in advance for any advice, resources or thoughts on the matter. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is having a similar issue with future sequential (or temporal) data, University of Oxford and Google Cloud AI have come up with a new architecture to handle all three types of input (past temporal, future temporal as well as static). It is called **Temporal Fusion Transformer** and, at least from reading the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.09363), looks like a neat fit. However, I have yet to implement and test it. There is also a [PyTorch Tutorial](https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/stallion.html) available.